# Shifting elements in a string

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to haskell and I wanted to make a function to take a string and add a certain number to shift the elements of the string.

e.g

```
addChars "abcd" 2
output -> "cdef"
```

I was able to do it but with just a single character using:

```
nextChar :: Char -> Int -> Char
nextChar x y= chr $ ord x + y
```

Comment: Do you know how to apply a function to all the elements of a list? You just need to apply `nextChar` to all the characters in your string, which is just a list of characters.

Comment: @user I can use map but on a predefined list of characters, but when I try to generalize it I get many errors, maybe I can't get the syntax right

Comment: @user I use `map` as something like this `xs = map nextChar ['a', 'b', 'c']` using the predefined list
and I edited the `nextChar` code to be like this `nextChar x = chr $ ord x + key` while `key` is a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `map`, here you will need to call `nextChar` with a value for the second parameter

```
addChars :: String -> Int -> String
addChars cs dc = map (`nextChar` dc) cs
```

Often in Haskell the parameters will be reversed, so we define a function:

```
nextChar :: Int -> Char -> Char
nextChar dc c = chr (ord c + dc)
```

and then we can define `addChars` as:

```
addChars :: Int -> String -> String
addChars dc cs = map (nextChar dc) cs
```

or shorter:

```
addChars :: Int -> String -> String
addChars = map . nextChar
```